# Select only numeric columns from dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, numeric

I have this **list** of dataframes as follows :

```
library(carData)
library(datasets)
l = list(Salaries,iris)
```

I only want to select the numeric columns in this list of datasets. Already tried `lapply` with the function `select_if(is.numeric)` but it did not work with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `select` with `where` in the newer version of `dplyr` - loop over the `list` with `map` and `select` the columns of the data.frames

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(l, ~ .x %>%
    select(where(is.numeric)))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lapply(l, Filter, f = is.numeric)
```

Answer (score 4):

base `R` option using `lapply` twice like this:

```r
library(carData)
library(datasets)

l = list(Salaries,iris)
lapply(l, \(x) x[, unlist(lapply(x, is.numeric), use.names = FALSE)])
#> [[1]]
#>     yrs.since.phd yrs.service salary
#> 1              19          18 139750
#> 2              20          16 173200
#> 3               4           3  79750
#> 4              45          39 115000
#> 5              40          41 141500
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#> 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#> 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#> 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Maybe `lapply(l, \(x) x[sapply(x, is.numeric)])` is more concise.